# Aggregate queries with self join

Tags: sql, postgresql

Database: Postgres

Table: users

```
id: int
created_at: Timestamp // When a user is created
first_active: Timestamp //When a user is active in the system.
```

Query Get percentage of users that were active in first 72 hours.

As of now I do

```
select count (*) from users;
```

Followed by

```
select count (*) from users where first_active <= created_at + + interval '72 hour'
```

And then do a division.

Is it possible to do it a single sql?

Comment: Use `count(*) over()` and conditional aggregation.

Comment: `select avg((first_active <= created_at + interval '72 hours')::int) from users;`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply combime them as both return a scalar valaue

the case when was only for the example as division by 0 is not allowed

```
select count(*)::DECIMAL(10,2) / 
  (CASE WHEN (select count(*) from users where first_active <= created_at + interval '72 hour') = 0 THEN 1 END
) from users;
```

| ?column? |
| --- |
| 0.00000000000000000000 |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TaFvdwbe)